# Add Bundle Version and Build to splash screen using PhoneGap

Tags: objective-c, cordova, xcode7

Using the latest PhoneGap what is the best guidance someone could give as to adding the Bundle Version and Build Number overlaying a PhoneGap Splash screen.  I see this on other apps but most likely those apps may not have been built with PhoneGap. From what I have read you could use a UIView controller to do this to the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.  I am not an Objective C coder and native apps are new to me so any guidance as to where to start would be helpful. I am on El Capitan using xCode 7.1.1. Is there a tutorial of sorts to getting this done? Is it a lengthy integration? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't implemented this but have thought about it a couple times... one way of getting a cross platform solution might be to stamp the bundle / app version or whatever other information you want dynamically added to the splash using ImageMagick, and the [Cordova hooks](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html) system to run a script each build to do this.  We have done similar with a script that sets the version numbers in config.xml for Jenkins builds, so that we can associate Jenkins output with test builds.  I would imagine the same mechanism could be used with the [Annotating capability](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#wmark_text) of Image Magick to have a platform independent way of achieving this.

Comment: I did think of something like this as well.  In which case I do have a Photoshop Actions Script that creates and resizes all versions of the splash screen to the resources folder. I could add in the info there.  I like your idea as well but was hoping to avoid any re-rastering of images. If it was a nice clean simple text overlay positioned at the bottom of the UI it would be the preferred solution. Thank you for your ideas! Pretty creative, I didn't know you could use ImageMagick in xCode. I have used it with PHP in the past and I am a bit familiar with it.