# How to add version number to cordova splash screen?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework

I've added the Cordova Splashscreen plugin to my Ionic project and it works OK.  Now I want to add a version number to the splash screen.  Is there a way to programatically do this without having to edit the Splash Screen PNG file every single time I release a new version?

Comment: There's a bit of a discussion on this here that may be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875536/add-bundle-version-and-build-to-splash-screen-using-phonegap

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working with Simon's suggestion!

Here's the command that stamps a version number to the bottom-center of a splash screen using ImageMagick:

```
'convert -pointsize 48 -fill \'#494949\' signing/splash.png -gravity south -annotate +0+100 ' + version + ' resources/splash.png'
```